# Script listed in Jade not accessible in my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pug

In running an express app, the Jade template includes two script lines:

```
  script(src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js")  <== library
  script(src="main.js")                                   <== my code
```

But when I call something defined in the first script from my JavaScript in main.js, I get the error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
```

The offending line is this one:

```
 var io = io.connect();
```

Which is defined in the first socket.io script. How can I include that script in a way that my code in main,js can find it?

If this was server side, I'd just 'require' it.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding accessing the io javascript**
You can check in your developer tools in network or console tab to find if the socket js is loading in your templates.

you can install it with node:

```
npm install socket.io    
var io = require('socket.io')(80);
```

Other than that you can go directly to this page https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js and copy the code from that page into a local js file (socket.js or whatever you'd like to call it) and then require it as you would any other file.

Or find a different cdn to try and access it from.

**Regarding the error you are getting**
Have you defined `io` anywhere?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Isn't it defined in the included file (the one  that I infer is not being loaded)?

Comment: Okay but the issue here is youre calling `.connect()` on an `io` object that you havent defined. You are defining `io = io.connect()` but the `io` in `io.connect()` hasnt been defined. if you get me.

Comment: The io object is the default global exported object of the lib socket.io. You can check this in the documentation of socket.io

Comment: yes which is usually defined like this  `var io = require('socket.io')(80);` but you havent defined `io` in your code so you cant call methods on it.

Comment: That helps. So where do I define it? This is client side code, so I can't just require it, right?

Comment: I would suggest using `npm install socket.io` and then defining it in your express app using require.

Comment: This way, like you said it will be on server side and you can just require it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this version

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.5/socket.io.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.5/socket.io.min.js

Socket io use browserify in order to compile the script into one file.

Probably the version you use is corrupt.
If this doesn't solve, try to use the npm socket-io.client lib.

```
npm install --save socket.io

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
```

Translate this into jade.

Comment: The first idea does not change things. I'll try the 'translate into Jade' option.

Comment: Rember to install it in the node server that run socket io

Comment: I'm using express.io, so it should be installed by default.